# A* orientation discretization

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, modelling

I have a space with obstacles I wish to find a path through. What I can do is discretize the space into a grid and use A* (or D* or whatever) to find a path through it. I wish to now add orientation to the algorithm. So the node location now becomes a 3d vector (x, y, phi). You can go from one node to another one only if they belong to an arc (both positions are on a circle and are oriented along the tangent lines). How do I discretize the space so that angles don't explode in a sense that by traversing the graph, the set of possible angles becomes finite?